# iOS: When VoiceOver is turned ON using the Accessibility shortcut of triple clicking Home Button, the screen gets turned off

Tags: ios, iphone

The accessibility elements are being read correctly in the background, i.e the labels being read can only be heard but cant see the screen as it blacks out, just the screen goes dark. Anybody come across the issue?
Verified this is in iOS 11 with iPhone 6s, iPhone 7 plus.
(Project is in Swift although it must not matter)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that with **3 finger triple tap on screen** , the above setting gets disabled. And the Accessibility Voice Over starts to work as normal, i.e reading the labels with the screen turned ON.